# Can you check if Exit() was called

Tags: delphi

Can a developer check if `Exit` was called?

```
try
  {do some stuff}
  If Condition then
    Exit;
finally
  {Can I check here if Exit was called without checking Condition again?}
end;
```

Comment: The answer is "No".

Comment: You can probably determine this, but it would be an awful hack.  I would reconsider the design of the flow control to be something more sensible, personally.

Comment: Why do you need/want this? If you show an actual example we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: If your condition is complex and you don't want waste time again, use a boolean variable and evaluate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I check here if `Exit` was called without checking `Condition` again?

No. If checking `Condition` again is expensive, or has side-effects, then you can use a local variable to indicate that `Condition` was `True`.

```
var
  LCondition: Boolean;
...
LCondition := False;
try
  // do stuff
  LCondition := Condition;
  if LCondition then
    Exit;
finally
  // now check LCondition
end;
```

Comment: This is what I normally do but I was curious to find out if there was an alternative. Thanks David

Comment: `Beginning with Delphi 2009, Exit can take a parameter specifying a result. The parameter must be of the same type as the result of the function.` This means that you can set some default result value of your function in case of exception is raised by passing that result as parameter to Exit. So maybe you won't even need to do your checking in finally part of the try finally block. Can't say for sure as you haven't shown whole code.